# convert json string to hash and retrieve hash items values in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string object which is basically in a json format and while trying to print it shows in console as

```
item = 
 {
        "id": "4c9f83e4-f479-48d0-9f92-3fff70a8f6ba",
         "item": "{&quot;business&quot;:&quot;1114&quot;,&quot;class&quot;:&quot;Demo&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;01-01-2014&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;dummy&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Finance&quot;}"

    }
```

I need to get the values of business, class, date etc and pass it as params to my method. So I tried to convert it into hashes as below

```
hash_item = JSON.parse (item)
```

and output in console shows as

```
The converted hash item is
{"guid"=>"4c9f83e4-f479-48d0-9f92-3fff70a8f6ba", "item"=>"{&quot;business&quot;:&quot;1114&quot;,&quot;class&quot;:&quot;Demo&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;01-01-2014&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;Dummy&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Finance&quot;}"}
```

But when I try to access the hash value for business as 
`hash_item['item']['business']` it shows

> "business"

since the value of item is a String in the hash_item. I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not. So is there any better idea or any inputs to retrieve the hash values . Please help.

**Updated Code:**

Actually I am implementing a queuing mechanism with right_aws gem for my application and the queue item returns a Message Instance of String format. so in my controller I am accessing the queue object as

```
def next
    @receiver = @queue.pop()
    if @receiver.present?
            respond_with(@receiver)
    end
end
```

And my next.json.erb would be

```
{
    "guid": "<%=@receiver.id%>",
     "item": "<%=generate_json_format(@receiver)%>"

}
```

my helper to generate json format is

```
def generate_json_format(sender)
    (JSON.parse (sender.body.gsub('=>', ':'))).to_json
    end
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual code? You say, "I have a string object which is basically in a json format," but unless it *is* valid JSON and not just "basically in a JSON format" you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Jordan I have updated my code in the original post.. I am not sure whether you will need more explanation/clarity to get a better understanding.

Comment: Yes.. its a valid json. I pasted {
        "id": "4c9f83e4-f479-48d0-9f92-3fff70a8f6ba",
         "item": "{&quot;business&quot;:&quot;1114&quot;,&quot;class&quot;:&quot;Demo&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;01-01-2014&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;dummy&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Finance&quot;}"

    } in JsonLint and it was showing valid json format.

Comment: But the problem is that the item is a String object with hashes...

Comment: I believe the generated JSON is not right. For instance, your method `generate_json_format` is substituting `=>` with `:` which is not needed. If you see the value for item which is `{&quot;business&quot;:&quot;1114&quot;,&quot;class&quot;:&quot;Demo&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;01-01-2014&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:&quot;dummy&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Finance&quot;}"` a string and not json hence you will never get the desired result.
Here is what I think your json should be like:
`item = {"guid" : "some_id", "item" : {"business" : 1114, "class" : "demo"}}`.